# Couchbase-Kafka-Connector error in zookeeper logs

Tags: apache-kafka, couchbase, apache-zookeeper

Iam new to Couchbase and Kafka. Whenever i insert message into Couchbase bucket say "xyz", connector picks it up and puts into kafka topic with same name ie "xyz". So far so good. But here i have a kafka consumer running which reads this topic and puts into another topic say "abc_123" but that never happens. Mainly iam seeing this error in zookeeper (which iam running as part of kafka) and wanted to know, if this is something which i can ignore or not.

> [2017-07-13 23:39:10,830] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when
>   processing sessionid:0x15d3d09116b000d type:create cxid:0x47b
>   zxid:0x551 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error
>   Path:/couchbase-kafka-connector2/default/913 Error:KeeperErrorCode =
>   NodeExists for /couchbase-kafka-connector2/default/913
>   (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)

Google search has no answers till now on the above specific error and iam curious to know why i always get this error as soon as message is put into couchbase bucket "xyz".

BTW, clearing buckets, reinstalling zookeeper, kafka, couchbase are all tried with no result. My kafka consumer code is pretty standard and i can provide if that helps, but iam curious about error seen in zookeeper console.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just starting with Couchbase connector for Kafka, I would recommend to look at new connector: https://github.com/couchbase/kafka-connect-couchbase/, it does not depend on Zookeeper directly, easier to setup and more reliable.